# Java JAAS configuration when Kerberos credential cache is externally managed

Tags: kerberos, jaas

Running our app as Java 17,

We connect to Kafka and DB using Kerberos using ticketcache.

When credential cache is managed externally managed. Do we need make renewTGT=true?

Also does renewTGT updates ticket cache? When it refreshes every 10 hrs for 7 days & gets new ticket after 7 days of expiration? Based on on our internal settings?

Turned on kerberos debugging for java..Not super clear on the flow.

We tried debugging the app and we can see the ticket is trying to get renewed when we turn on renewTGT, However not clear whether it updates ticket cache also not understanding what will happen when tickets cannt be renewed after the expiration date.